# LocalStorage addClass multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm almost there to get what I want but here is the problem. First, added Class on click function, and save that on local storage. Here, I've achieved it but the only problem is I would like to save multiple clicks, so here when I click one, the first div is active and others are being removed, when two is clicked the second div is active, other(one and three) are removed from being active. When I click both one and two, I want both to be active and save that in json local storage.

Here is [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6smofv/221/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.relative_holder').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $nextDiv = $(this).closest('.list-content-single');

    var $divs = $('.list-content-single').removeClass('visitednw');

    if (!$nextDiv.length)
      $nextDiv = $divs.first();

    $nextDiv.addClass('visitednw');
    localStorage.setItem("activeDiv", $nextDiv.index('.list-content-single'));
  });

  var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem("activeDiv");
  if (activeIndex)
    $('.list-content-single').removeClass('visitednw').eq(activeIndex).addClass('visitednw')
});
```

```css
.visitednw {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-content-single" id="first">
  <h1> first div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-first">
    One
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list-content-single" id="second">
  <h1> second div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-second">
    Two
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list-content-single" id="third">
  <h1> third div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-third">
    Three
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that once every div has been activated once they're all continuously stored as active and there is no way to 'deactivate' one?

Comment: I don't need to deactivate. I'm okay with it being 'permanent' addClass and store it. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot make a snippet since localStorage is not allowed at JSFiddle and Stackoverflow

Comment: Do you mean if a refresh comes the active div will still be active?

Comment: @Henry yeah of course

Comment: @mplungjan, everything is working. I just need to store multiple values so multiple item can have active class.

Comment: @mplungjan, that is what I'm having difficulty on.

Comment: JSON.stringify/JSON.parse, not encode/decode sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set and get an array of indices to localStorage and set the class to the right list items.

Since localStorage only support strings, you can use

```
localStorage.setItem("activeIndices", JSON.stringify(activeIndices));
```

and

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("activeIndices"));
```

I've made an **updated Fiddle** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a98vxsj1/).

Comment: Hi, as per your fiddle, when i click lets say second, it will add active on first and second. When i click on second, i only need to active on second and if i need third too, then i should be able to click on third and active only the current element.

Comment: Was a small bug; `for ... in` loop instead of `for ... of`. I've updated the Fiddle link.

Comment: Almost there! Now, it won't store cache.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried clearing localStorage in Dev Tools?

Comment: Works fine on JSfiddle. And at my localhost site as well but this is what happens: 
When i click on items, it adds active class on all selected item, but when i reload page, it wont show up. I have to click on one the the item that i've clicked on before and then only active class shows up based on cache.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the code from the [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a98vxsj1/)?

Answer (score 0):

### Explained

Seeing how you're currently doing it, it seems somewhat inefficient, so I've written it this way, this way will run things only when necessary, rather than run & execute everything within the `$(document).ready` function.

As you can see, I've broken the solution up into an array of small, concise and simple functions, this is to ensure that the solution is simple and lightweight. There's a number of functions that are used just to handle the state alone, this is purely because on Stackoverflow, as an example, you can't actually use `localStorage` within snippets, hence the plain ol' `try, catch` solution.

Anyway, you can see when the DOM is ready, two functions are fired, `dispatchEvents` and `render`, I went with these names yet again for the sake of simplicity, to ensure that the purpose of the function is very clear.  Then of course, the `clickHandler` function is responsible for managing how to update the state, once the state has been updated, the `updateState` function is fired, from here it'll just re-render the UI and log the state, it's as simple as that.

#### PS

You may wish to use more jQuery than I've used, I've literally only used it for the `ready` function, and that's about it.

```js
// Just a global variable for the local storage key.
const stateName = 'activeDiv';

// Global/public state in the event that local storage can't be used. 
let state = {};


// A simple function to get the state of the application.
const getState = () => {
  try {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stateName));
    if (typeof data != 'object' || data == null) {
      return state;
    } else {
      state = data;
      return state;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return state;
  }
};


// A simple function to update the application state.
const updateState = newState => {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(stateName, JSON.stringify(newState));
  } catch (e) {
    // todo 
  }

  state = getState();
  console.clear();
  console.log(state);

  render();
};


// A simple function to update the UI. 
const render = () => {
  const local = getState();
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".list-content-single");

  if (local.active != null) {
    divs.forEach(div => {

      if (local.active.indexOf(div.id) >= 0) {
        div.className = "visitednw list-content-single";
      } else {
        div.className = "list-content-single";
      }
    });
  }
};


// A simple function to update the state when a button is clicked.
const clickHandler = () => {
  const e = event || window.event;
  const div = e.target.parentElement;
  const key = div.id;
  const local = getState();

  if (local[key] == null) {
    local[key] = 1; // The default value, clicked once already. 
  } else {
    local[key] += 1;
  }

  if (local.active == null) {
    local.active = [];
  }

  if (local.active.indexOf(key) == -1) {
    local.active.push(key);
  }

  updateState(local);

  // Double whammy.
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};


// A simple function to manage what events handle what.
const dispatchEvents = () => {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".list-content-single");
  divs.forEach(div => {
    const btn = div.querySelector(".relative_holder");
    btn.onclick = () => clickHandler();
  })
};


// A simple function to be fired for $(document).ready.
const onReady = () => {
  render();
  dispatchEvents();
};


// Good ol' $(document).ready.
$(document).ready(onReady);
```

```css
.visitednw {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-content-single" id="first">
  <h1> first div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-first">
    One
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list-content-single" id="second">
  <h1> second div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-second">
    Two
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list-content-single" id="third">
  <h1> third div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-third">
    Three
   </a>
</div>
```

### ES5 Version

If you're not familiar with ES6, not to worry, here's an ES5 implementation.

```js
// Just a global variable for the local storage key.
var stateName = 'activeDiv';

// Global/public state in the event that local storage can't be used. 
var state = {};


// A simple function to get the state of the application.
var getState = function() {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stateName));

    if (typeof data != 'object' || data == null) {
      return state;
    } else {
      state = data;
      return state;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return state;
  }
};


// A simple function to update the application state.
var updateState = function(newState) {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(stateName, JSON.stringify(newState));
  } catch (e) {
    // todo 
  }

  state = getState();
  console.clear();
  console.log(state);
  render();
};


// A simple function to update the UI. 
var render = function() {
  var local = getState();
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".list-content-single");

  if (local.active != null) {
    divs.forEach(function(div) {

      if (local.active.indexOf(div.id) >= 0) {
        div.className = "visitednw list-content-single";
      } else {
        div.className = "list-content-single";
      }
    });
  }
};


// A simple function to update the state when a button is clicked.
var clickHandler = function() {
  var e = event || window.event;
  var div = e.target.parentElement;
  var key = div.id;
  var local = getState();

  if (local[key] == null) {
    local[key] = 1; // The default value, clicked once already. 
  } else {
    local[key] += 1;
  }

  if (local.active == null) {
    local.active = [];
  }

  if (local.active.indexOf(key) == -1) {
    local.active.push(key);
  }

  updateState(local);

  // Double whammy.
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};


// A simple function to manage what events handle what.
var dispatchEvents = function() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".list-content-single");
  divs.forEach(function(div) {
    var btn = div.querySelector(".relative_holder");
    btn.onclick = () => clickHandler();
  })
};


// A simple function to be fired for $(document).ready.
var onReady = function() {
  render();
  dispatchEvents();
};


// Good ol' $(document).ready.
$(document).ready(onReady);
```

```css
.visitednw {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-content-single" id="first">
  <h1> first div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-first">
    One
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list-content-single" id="second">
  <h1> second div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-second">
    Two
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list-content-single" id="third">
  <h1> third div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-third">
    Three
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I need to be able to store multiple value. lets say, if i click first and second, both of them should be stored as active.

Comment: @NishDekardo Okay, I've just updated that, thank you for clarifying that for me! :)

Comment: Good solve. ES6 notation might be a little confusing for someone asking this type of question though.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yay or nay for an ES5 solution? Honestly, I mostly use ES6 just because it's often less to type! Screw it, I'll do it anyway! :)

Comment: agreed, ES6 would be preferred in our own work, just afraid it might confuse someone starting out like the OP seems to be, I could just be over analyzing though :).

Comment: @DelightedD0D You have a point because a guy that I'm personally teaching, he didn't understand a functional style approach to a specific problem that he had, I showed him it, and I shouldn't have, but I just assumed he knew ES6 to some extent, so I just walked him through the basics... I mean once you know, the difference is next to none! :)

Comment: @mplungjan That may be the case... I'm not disagreeing with you there, I simply meant that it's a loose implementation of ES5 standards... I mean the only reason I did that so it's more beginner friendly... I'm not gonna get caught up in that level of analysis, but thank you for your input.... FYI. Some sources consider something as subtle as ```Array.forEach``` as being ES5... But again, I'm not gonna get into the nitty gritty of it! :)

Comment: Ah, I missed the forEach which is indeed not supported for nodeLists by all browser that support querySelector. It would need a polyfill too

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, basically storing all the currently active ids as a comma separated string and convert that to an array when you need to use it:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6smofv/317/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // set initial display on page load
  displayVisited();

  // update display on click
  $('.relative_holder').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleVisited(this.id);
  });
});


function displayVisited() {
  $('.list-content-single').removeClass('visitednw')
  var activeIds = getActiveIds();
  if (activeIds.length > 0) {
    var idString = '#' + activeIds.join(",#");
    $(idString).closest('.list-content-single').addClass('visitednw')
  }
}

function toggleVisited(id) {
  var activeIds = getActiveIds();
  // if the given id is not in our array already, add it
  if ($.inArray(id, activeIds) === -1) {
    activeIds.push(id);
  } else {
    // if the given id is in our array already, remove it
    activeIds = removeVisited(activeIds, id);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("activeDivs", activeIds.join(','));
  displayVisited();
}

// get the array of visited ids with the given id removed
function removeVisited(storedIds, removedId) {
  var cleanIds = [];
  // if the given id is in our array, remove it
  if ($.inArray(removedId, storedIds) !== -1) {
    $.each(storedIds, function(i, currentId) {
      if (currentId !== removedId) {
        cleanIds.push(currentId);
      }
    });
  }
  return cleanIds;
}

// get an array of active ids from local storage
function getActiveIds() {
  var activeIds = localStorage.getItem("activeDivs");
  console.log(activeIds)
  return activeIds ? activeIds.split(',') : [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer has some methods to add, save stuff to local storage and deal with it missing if we try to access it.  I also added the ability to toggle it OFF by clicking it again, easy to turn that part off if you need just by setting the `inuse` to true always.  It is pretty verbose so you can see what is going on at each line.  This should also handle more items (by index) if you add more - instead of that index use you might consider a data attribute so that the order of the HTML is not tied so closely to the storage.

```js
//console.clear();
var itemName = "activeDiv";

function saveItems(savethese) {
  // Put the object into storage
  localStorage.setItem(itemName, JSON.stringify(savethese));
}

function getSavedItems() {
  // Retrieve the object from storage and parse if it is there
  let retrievedItems = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
  let parsedItems = (!retrievedItems || !retrievedItems.length) ? [] : JSON.parse(retrievedItems);

  return parsedItems;
}

function setItem(sel, index, inuse) {
  return {
    id: index,
    idval: sel[0].id,
    inuse: inuse
  };
}

function addOrReplace(array, item) {
  const i = array.findIndex(_item => _item.id === item.id);
  if (i > -1) {
    array[i] = item;
  } else {
    array.push(item);
  }
  return array;
}
$(function() {
  $('.relative_holder').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let items = getSavedItems();
    let $parent = $(this).closest('.list-content-single');
    let $divs = $('.list-content-single');
    let tindex = $divs.index($parent);
    let checkMe = items.find(obj => {
      return obj.id === tindex
    });
    let isPresent = !(checkMe === undefined);
    let isSet = isPresent && checkMe.inuse;
    //console.log("tindex:", tindex);
    //console.log("items:", items);
    $parent.toggleClass('visitednw',!isSet);
    var item = setItem($parent, tindex, !isSet);
    items = addOrReplace(items, item);
    saveItems(items);
  });
  // set initial values based on prior setting
  (function() {
    var possible = $('.list-content-single');
    let itemsSet = getSavedItems();

    var i = 0;
    var ilen = itemsSet.length;
    //console.log(itemsSet);
    for (i; i < ilen; i++) {
      possible.eq(itemsSet[i].id).toggleClass('visitednw', itemsSet[i].inuse);
    }
  })();
});
```

```css
.visitednw {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-content-single" id="first">
  <h1> first div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-first">
    One
  </a>
</div>
<div class="list-content-single" id="second">
  <h1> second div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-second">
    Two
  </a>
</div>
<div class="list-content-single" id="third">
  <h1> third div</h1>
  <a class="relative_holder" href="#" id="btn-third">
    Three
   </a>
</div>
```